# adding a define preprocessor in Cmake gives redefinition error on catch

Tags: c++, cmake, try-catch

I have a simple test where i am using catch2 library. test is as follows:

```
#include <catch2/catch.hpp>
TEST_CASE("Pass Tests")
{
    REQUIRE(1 == 1);
}
```

If we want catch to use our main.cpp instead of definig its own main then we have to add #define CATCH_CONFIG_RUNNER in main.cpp, but i want to add this define preprocessor in my CMakeList rather than main.cpp so here's my main.cpp:

```
#include <catch2/catch.hpp>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
      // bootstrap Catch, running all TEST_CASE sequences.
      auto result = Catch::Session().run(argc, argv);
      return (result < 0xFF ? result : 0xFF);
}
```

and my CMakeList goes as:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(main)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

file(GLOB_RECURSE sources main.cpp  Test.cpp)

add_executable (main ${sources})
target_compile_definitions(main PRIVATE -DCATCH_CONFIG_RUNNER)
```

My problem is when I am compiling I get the errors "multiple definitions of a catch" but when I add #define CATCH_CONFIG_RUNNER directly in the main.cpp, it doesn't give me any error and runs perfectly. What can I do to make it run with CMake rather than adding it to my main.cpp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Only one source file** should have `CATCH_CONFIG_RUNNER` macro defined.

`target_compile_definitions` adds the definition for *every* source file of the given target. In you case, these are `main.cpp` and `Test.cpp` files. Thus you have "multiple  definitions" error.

For add compile definitions only for one source file, set property [COMPILE_DEFINITIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_sf/COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.html) for that source only:

```
set_property(SOURCE main.cpp PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "CATCH_CONFIG_RUNNER")
```